# is this vowel sound [ɨ]?

Tags: phonetics

the reason why I'm asking this question is because today I read a study which claimed that word-final vowels are "weakened" in my native language when pronounced in isolation, I tried Pronouncing a word with final /i/ and it sounded like [this](https://voca.ro/1ei8uCut7SAb), is this vowel [ɨ]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above, that is, it's somewhere in between. Your F1 is a bit high and your F2 is low, which moves it towards a central vowel. But it's not high enough F1 or low enough F2 to be ɨ, so it stands between [i] and [ɨ]. Compare your to Ladefoged, House, Esling, Wells [reference values](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html).